# Is using jquery form submit without php secure enough

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I have a form on my site where users can make new accounts. The "submit" button on the form is not a true submit button.  It's an html `type='button'`. when this is clicked I use the jquery:
`('#form').submit();` to submit the form.  If javascript is disabled, the form can't submit because the "submit" button is only a button and nothing happens.  I was wondering if this type of security is truly secure or are there ways of still submitting this form?

Comment: You're considering this secure?

Comment: You don't have any security at all. Submitting a form has no special meaning. Anyone can still send you any HTTP POST or HTTP GET request they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still trigger the submit event by opening the console and typing

```
document.forms[0].submit()
```

Security on the client is never truly secure without help from server-side validation.

Comment: you could even create a new form, move the input elements from the old form to the new one you created, append to body, and submit, bypassing all submit events you could possibly define on the other form.

Comment: are you saying the user can write his/her own html on top of mine?

Comment: Yes, anything you can do with html/css/javascript, the client can do.

Answer (score 1):

NO.  Relying on ANY client side (or lack there of) validation is never secure

Answer (score 1):

User can change `type='button'` to `type='submit'` easily.

**The true security comes from the server side.**